# SAPUI5 odata bind table with input parameters in controller

Tags: data-binding, odata, sapui5, input-parameters

I need to pass dynamic valued input parameter to calculation view via Odata binding to grid table. I can get calculation view result from Odata with following syntax:

```
...odata/SERVICE.xsodata/DataSetParameters(P_END_DATE=datetime'2013/07/10',P_START_DATE=datetime'2013/07/03')/Results?$format=json
```

I am binding grid table with following code in controller (date will be dynamic in actual application)

```
var gridTable = _this.getView().byId(gridName);
gridTable.setModel(oModel);
gridTable.bindRows("DataSet(P_END_DATE=datetime\'2013/07/10\',P_START_DATE=datetime\'2013/07/03\')", null, null, aFilters);
```

In runtime I am getting following errors

`No key property &#x0027;P_END_DATE&#x0027; exists in type...No key property 'P_END_DATE' exists in type  ...Collection 'DataSet' is not directly accessible....Collection 'DataSet' is not directly accessible.`

Can anyone help me to know what is the correct syntax to pass the parameter from odata binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODATA collection you expose will be available at **/Results** and is not directly accessible with /DataSet.

A NavigationProperty is required to retrieve the results from the parameterized call.
So you will have to change your binding path to this

```
DataSetParameters(param1=value,param2=value)/Results
```

Controller code        `gridTable.bindRows("DataSetParameters(P_END_DATE=datetime\'2013/07/10\',P_START_DATE=datetime\'2013/07/03\')/Results", null, null, aFilters);`

Comment: Now oData url can build correctly and data is retrieving (checked in Chrome console) but data is not showing in grid table. In console can see the following error `2017-02-24 21:35:12.243000 The following problem occurred: HTTP request failed400,Bad Request,{ "error": { "code": "", "message": { "lang": "en-US", "value": "Collection 'DataSet' is not directly accessible."}}} - ` My grid binding code looks like `gridTable.bindRows("oDataModel>/DataSetParameters(P_END_DATE=datetime\'2013/07/10\',P_START_DATE=datetime\'2013/07/03\')/Results", null, null, aFilters);`

Comment: Is oDataModel your data model? if that is so, then you are not binding correctly

Comment: Yes oDataModel is my model name defined in manifest.json. I am following the same syntax for all bindings only difference is there has no parameter. Do I need to set model as table.setModel(oDataModel) and dataset with parameter as you mentioned?

Comment: The way you are binding it is incorrect. "oDataModel>/DataSetParameters(......" would work in the XML notation, however for Javascript in you controller it's different

Comment: You will have to do it this way `gridTable.bindRows("/DataSetParameters(P_END_DATE‌​=datetime\'2013/07/1‌​0\',P_START_DATE=dat‌​etime\'2013/07/03\')‌​/Results", null, null, aFilters); 
gridTable.setModel(oDataModel);`

Comment: If you know the syntax can you please share it with me, really it will be very helpful. For an update now with this syntax I can see data in grid table but still throwing error popup and in console same error as I mentioned earlier. If you have any idea about solution please share it with me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried with this as well but `gridTable.setModel(oDataModel);` was before  of the line `gridTable.bindRows("/DataSetParameters(P_END_DATE‌​=datetime‌​\'2013/07/1‌​0\',P_S‌​TART_DATE=dat‌​etime‌​\'2013/07/03\')‌​/Re‌​sults", null, null, aFilters); ` but it is not showing data. Practically it is not triggering any batch request in console with this.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to share more code as to how you initiate the OData model, create and bind the table

Comment: I am defining model in manifest and then assigning at init. and next getting model from view and these codes are as :`var oModel = this.getView().getModel("oDataModel"); gridTable.setModel(oModel);gridTable.bindRows("oDataModel>/DataSetParameters(P_END_DATE‌​=datetime\'2013/07/1‌​0\',P_START_DATE=dat‌​etime\'2013/07/03\')‌​/Results", null, null, aFilters);` about binding these process I am following.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136590/discussion-between-stephen-s-and-suman-biswas).

Comment: For your kind informaiton, your information solved my issue, I was getting two error message but found this is happening due to other reason. So your solution finally clicked the solution. **Thanks a lot for your help.**